# How do I dispose and v-if checks in v-dialog?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have v-dialog. For this, I make checks with v-if. But when v-dialog is opened 3-4 times in a row, the background turns black and the fields inside the v-dialog do not function as in the normal function.

When multiple v-if checks are done, how can I dispose the other v-dialog when another v-dialog is opened.

My code.

```
                   <v-dialog
                      v-model="editDiolog"
                      max-width="800px"
                      persistent >

                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                      <v-list-item link @click="editModalOpen(item)">
                        <v-list-item-action class="mr-2">
                          <v-icon color="primary">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                        </v-list-item-action>
                        <v-list-item-title>
                          <span class="navi-text">{{ "Edit" }}</span>
                        </v-list-item-title>
                      </v-list-item>
                    </template>
                   <v-card>
                     <v-tabs>
                       <v-tab>
                   <!-- Something here... -->
                       </v-tab>
                   </v-tabs>
                  </v-card>
           <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
                    <v-tab-item :eager="true">
                      <v-card flat>
                        <v-card-text>
                          <v-container>
                           <div  v-if="Type =='Condition1'"></div>
                           <div  v-if="Type =='Condition2'"></div>
                           <div  v-if="Type =='Condition3'"></div>
                           <div  v-if="Type =='Condition4'"></div>
                         </v-container>
                        </v-card-text>
                      </v-card>
                    </v-tab-item>
             </v-tabs-items>
```

Comment: remove `persistent` from `v-dialog` props

Comment: this didn't work for me @MohammadReza Abbasi

Comment: Like reproduction snippet? @tony19

Comment: Yes, or codepen or codesandbox.